# How can we use Spring and Hibernate Framework with Java 1.4

Tags: spring, hibernate

We have a Java project which was developed on 1.4 version and we do not want to change the Java version with newer version but We want to use Spring and Hibernate Framework with Java 1.4 .

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of spring that is working with Java 1.4:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

and Hibernate that is compatible with above spring version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
</dependency>
```